# Saving received Notification data to Firebase Database from FirebaseMessagingService class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to save data to Firebase Data after receiving notification from FCM. I want to save data from FirebaseMessagingService class on all cases (app get killed/background/foreground/). I have been using the payload data and successfully able to create the notification on all time no matter the app is in background/fore background/killed.

Notifications are displayed always on both devices and data are received

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

         if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

             String notificationID= remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationID");
             String notificationMessage= remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationMessage");

             ****** HERE IS CODE TO SHOW NOTIFICATION *****


          // Save data after showing Notification

        DatabaseReference  ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

          ref
            .child("Notifications")
            .child(notificationID)
            .setValue("received").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d("Notification saved", notificationID);
                }
            });


        }
   }
```